# Unitary operator on $\mathcal{H}$ and continuous function $f: [0, 1]\to \mathcal{B(H)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

For unitary operator $U$ on $\mathcal{H}$, prove that there is a continuous function $f: [0, 1]\to \mathcal{B(H)}$ such that $f(t)$ is unitary and $f(0)=U$ and $f(1)=I$

I tried to use every unitary operator on a Hilbert space can be written as $U=\exp(iA)$ for some Hermitian $A$. But that didn't seem to be going anywhere

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Take $f(t)=exp(i(1-t)A)$.

Comment: Ruy  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Mind that $A$ may be unbounded if the spectrum of $U$ is equal to entire unit circle.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc.  If you take $A$ to be the Borel functional calculus with the right branch of the logarithm, it is possible to get $\|A\|\leq \pi$.

Comment: @Ruy That's right. But I would prefer to apply the functional calculus directly to $U$ and get the integral over $(-\pi,\pi]$ of $e^{ix}$ and then rescale $x.$